# Determine between files and folders using cURL

Tags: php, ftp, curl

I'm writing a script to download files from an FTP server using cURL + PHP, at the moment I am just trying to build a complete file structure, here's the code I'm using so far:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://www.example.com");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'NLST');
    // or
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'LIST -a');

    $ftp=curl_exec($curl);
    $directory=split("[\n|\r]",$ftp);

    echo("<pre>".print_r($directory,true)."</pre>");

    foreach($directory as $key=>$value)
        if($value=='') 
            unset($directory[$key]);

    echo("<pre>".print_r($directory,true)."</pre>");
    curl_close ($curl);

?>
```

I can use either `NLST` or the `LIST` function, but what I want to do is programatically determine what are files and what are folders.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you decided to use cURL instead of PHP's FTP functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php)? Are there any advantage? With FTP functions you could probably do the same easier way

Comment: Agree with Laimoncijus. Use php's built in ftp. curl is isn't your best option here.

Comment: I am building a proof of concept using both the built in FTP functions and cURL so I can measure the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user group         24 Apr 25  2009 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x   2 user group       4096 Feb 21  2009 sample
```

I found out myself, the 1st character of the permission string dictates whether it is a directory or not.